# Why does adding elements of schema.TypeSet forces replacement in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: we're building a new TF provider.

Our schema definition looks as follows:

```
"foo": {
    Type:        schema.TypeInt,
    ...
},
"bar": {
    Type:        schema.TypeSet,
    Optional:    true,
    Elem: &schema.Resource{
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "xxx": {
                Type:         schema.TypeString,
                Required:     true,
                ForceNew:     true,
                ValidateFunc: validation.StringIsNotEmpty,
            },
            "yyy": {
                Type:         schema.TypeString,
                Required:     true,
                ForceNew:     true,
                ValidateFunc: validation.StringIsNotEmpty,
            },
            "zzz": {
                Type:        schema.TypeInt,
                Required:    true,
                ForceNew:    true,
            },
        },
    },
},
```

So there's no `ForceNew:     true,` on for a `bar` attribute on a top level but when I update my resource from

```
resource "aaa" "before" {
  foo = 2
}
```

->

```
resource "aaa" "before" {
  foo = 2
  bar {
    xxx = "aaa"
    yyy = "bbb"
    zzz = 3
  }
}
```

and yet I can see

```
+ bar { # forces replacement
          + xxx         = "aaa"
          + yyy = "bbb"
          + zzz      = 3
        }
```

Comment: It does seem to work if I drop `ForceNew:    true` for `xxx`, `yyy`, `zzz` attributes.

Comment: but I'm not sure that's the "right" fix

Comment: `ForceNew = true` is assigned in the attribute schema for each nested argument in `bar`, and therefore it triggers a Delete/Create operation on modification as expected. Please explain why you expect different behavior than what is coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDKv2 `ForceNew` feature is a convenience helper for a common case where any change to a particular argument requires replacing an object.

It seems like in your case you need a more specific rule. From what you've described it seems like you'd need to replace only if there's an item being *removed* from the set, because adding new items and removing old items are the only two possible changes to a set.

Any time when the built-in helpers don't work you can typically implement a more specific rule using arbitrary code by implementing [a `CustomizeDiff` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences).

A `CustomizeDiff` function with similar behavior to `ForceNew` would have a structure like the following:

```
func exampleCustomizeDiff(d *ResourceDiff, meta interface{}) error {
    old, new := d.GetChange("bar")
    if barChangeNeedsReplacement(old, new) {
        d.ForceNew("bar")
    }
    return nil
}
```

You will need to provide a definition of `barChangeNeedsReplacement` that implements whatever logic decides that replacement is needed.

I believe an attribute of `TypeSet` will appear in `old` and `new` as  [`*schema.Set`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk@v1.17.2/helper/schema#Set) values, and so if you type-assert to that type then you can use the methods of that type to perform standard set operations to make your calculation.

For example, if the rule were to require replacement only if there is an item in `old` that isn't in `new` then you could perhaps write it like this:

```
func barChangeNeedsReplacement(old, new any) bool {
    oldSet := old.(*schema.Set)
    newSet := new.(*schema.Set)

    removedSet := oldSet.Difference(newSet)
    return removedSet.Len() > 0
}
```

If that isn't quite the rule you wanted then hopefully you can see how to modify this example to implement the rule you need.